# How to run a csh script from a sh script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csh

I was wondering if there is a way to source a csh script from a sh script. Below is an example of what is trying to be implemented:

script1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

source script2
```

script2:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

setenv TEST 1234
set path = /home/user/sandbox
```

When I run sh script1.sh, I get syntax errors generated from script2 (expected since we are using a different Shebang). Is there a way I can run script2 through script1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `source script2` run it as:

```
csh -f script2
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your use case depends on retaining environment variables set by the `csh` script, try adding this to the beginning of `script1`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$csh_executed" -ne 1 ]; then
    csh_executed=1 exec csh -c "source script2;
                                exec /bin/sh \"$0\" \"\$argv\"" "$@"
fi

# rest of script1
```

If the `csh_executed` variable is not set to 1 in the environment, run a `csh` script that sources `script2` then executes an instance of `sh`, which will retain the changes to the environment made in `script2`. `exec` is used to avoid creating new processes for each shell instance, instead just "switching" from one shell to the next. Setting `csh_executed` in the environment of the `csh` command ensures that we don't get stuck in a loop when `script1` is re-executed by the `csh` instance.

---

Unfortunately, there is one drawback that I don't think can be fixed, at least not with my limited knowledge of `csh`: the second invocation of `script1` receives all the original arguments as a single string, rather than a sequence of distinct arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `source` there; it runs the given script inside your existing shell, without spawning a subprocess. Obviously, your sh process can't run something like that which isn't a sh script.

Just call the script directly, assuming it is executable:

```
script2
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can come to *sourcing* a script with a different executor than your original script is to use `exec`. `exec` will replace the running process space with the new process. Unlike `source`, however, when your `exec`-ed program ends, the entire process ends. So you can do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /path/to/csh/script
```

but you can't do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /path/to/csh/script
some-other-command
```

However, are you sure you really want to *source* the script? Maybe you just want to run it in a subprocess:

```
#!/bin/sh

csh -f /path/to/csh/script
some-other-command
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. After reading your answer I see that I meant to run it as a subprocess. Forgive my haste but I am still getting use to posting.

Answer (score 0):

You want the settings in your csh script to apply to the sh script that invokes it.

Basically, you can't do that, though there are some (rather ugly) ways you could make it work. If you *execute* your csh script, it will set those variables in the context of the process running the script; they'll vanish as soon as it returns to the caller.

Your best bet is simply to write a new version of your csh script *as an sh script*, and `source` or `.` it from the calling sh script.

You could translate your csh script:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

setenv TEST 1234
set path = /home/user/sandbox
```

to this:

```
export TEST=1234
export PATH=/home/user/sandbox
```

(csh treats the shell array variable `$path` specially, tying it to the environment variable `$PATH`. sh and its derivatives don't do that, they deal with `$PATH` itself directly.)

Note that a script intended to be sourced should *not* have a `#!` line at the top, since it doesn't make sense to execute it in its own process; you need to execute its contents in the context of the caller.

If maintaining two copies of the script, one to be `source`d from csh or tcsh scripts and another to be `source`d or `.`ed from sh/ksh/bash/zsh script, is not practical, there are other solutions. For example, your script can print a series of `sh` commands to be executed; you can then do something like

```
eval `./foo.csh`
```

(line endings will pose some issues here).

Or you can modify the csh script so it sets the required environment variables and then invokes some specified command, which could be a new interactive shell; this is inconvenient, since it doesn't set those variables in the interactive shell you're running.

If a software package requires some special environment variables to be set, it's common practice to provide scripts called, for example, `setup.sh` and `setup.csh`, so that sh/ksh/bash/zsh users can do:

```
. /path/to/package/setup.sh
```

and csh/tcsh users can do:

```
source /path/to/package/setup.csh
```

Incidentally, this command:

```
set path = /home/user/sandbox
```

in your sample script is probably not a good idea. It *replaces* your entire `$PATH` with just a single directory, which means you won't be able to execute simple commands like `ls` unless you specify their full paths.  You'd usually want something like:

```
set path = ( $path /home/user/sandbox )
```

or, in sh:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/user/sandbox
```